# Going back to the fragment from fragment activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have to go back from Fragment Activity to a certain fragment. I searched a lot but have some errors with answers.

I override the `onBackPressed` in fragment activity like below. But `fragment` shows an error.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        My_Fragment fragment = new My_Fragment ();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.my_fragment, fragment, "fragment").addToBackStack(null).commit(); //here fragment shows an error. 
    }
```

Error : Wrong 2nd argument type. Found "My_Fragment",required "android.app.Fragment"
Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you add the error to your answer, please?

Comment: First remove the super call

Comment: no need to replace fragment in onBackPressed() method.When you start activity fragment don't remove fragment at time.

Comment: Try using `getSupportFragmentManager()` in place of `getFragmentManager()` (assuming you're inside a `FragmentActivity`). And as @yshahak said, remove the `super` call.